# How to determine why an alert dialog was displayed by Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I am trying to fix a bug in a Chrome extension. When the extension is installed an alert dialog containing the message "undefined" will be displayed seemingly at random. This does not happen when the extension is not installed.

There is not one call to alert, confirm, or prompt in the extension source code. How do I find out why the alert dialog is being displayed?

I have attempted adding the following code to one of the background scripts and to one of the content scripts.

```
var originalWindowAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function() {
  console.trace();
  return originalWindowAlert.apply(window, arguments);
}
```

I have confirmed that this technique works when used [in a webpage](https://sullivanandkey.com/examples/JavaScriptAlertExample.html), but it is not working for the extension.

I have also built Chromium from source code and I am able to reproduce it but so far I have not been able to figure out how to determine the origin of the alert dialog. I have set a breakpoint in the RenderFrameHostImpl::RunModalAlertDialog function but I see no way to determine what caused the breakpoint to be hit.

I am getting desperate.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question on the Chromium Extensions Google Group. I got the following very useful response from Scott Fortmann-Roe.

If you do the following in a content script:

```
var originalWindowAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function() {
    console.trace();
    return originalWindowAlert.apply(window, arguments);
}
```

I don't believe it will actually intercept alerts triggered by the page as you are overriding the content script's window.alert method which is different from the page's method (content script JS is isolated from page JS).

To modify the page's alert method you'll probably need to inject a script tag into the page. E.g. something along these lines in the content script:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = `
var originalWindowAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function() { 
    console.trace()
    return originalWindowAlert.apply(window, arguments);
} `;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```